# "TypeError: sheet.getMaxColumns is not a function" in my Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that runs daily at midnight. It is supposed to replace any empty cells in Sheet `gainsArchive` with `0`. The script is gobbled together from other scripts I found on the web. It used to work, but I must have changed something in the process, so it now returns the error:
`TypeError: sheet.getMaxColumns is not a function`.
What did I do wrong?

```
function zeroing() {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("***my_sheet_ID***");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('gainsArchive'));
  var maxcolumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var maxrows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  range = sheet.getSheetByName('gainsArchive').getRange(1, 1, maxrows, maxcolumns) ;
  range.setValues(range.getValues().map(row => row.map(cell => !cell ? 0 : cell)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this fix:

```
function zeroing() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('***my_sheet_ID***');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('gainsArchive');
  var maxcolumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var maxrows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, maxrows, maxcolumns);
  range.setValues(range.getValues().map(row => row.map(cell => !cell ? 0 : cell)));
}
```

#### Explanation:

In the original code, `sheet` corresponds to [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) (that's what's returned by [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid), but [getMaxColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns) is a method of [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) instead, not `Spreadsheet`.